# How to split a string using shell-like rules in C++?

Tags: c++, string, shell, parsing

I have strings that look like shell command lines:

```
string c = "/path/to/binary arg1 arg2 \"arg3 has multiple words\"";
string c2 = "/path/to/binary arg1 'arg2 could be single-quoted also';
```

My goal is simple: I just want to split the string in a manner similar to how a command-line shell would. I'm not looking for fancy functions like wildcard or environment variable expansion (yet). I would like to just split each string into its various pieces:

```
vector<string> pieces = split_shell(c);
// pieces[0] == "/path/to/binary"
// pieces[1] == "arg1"
// pieces[2] == "arg2"
// pieces[3] == "arg3 has multiple words"

vector<string> pieces2 = split_shell(c2);
// pieces2[0] == "/path/to/binary"
// pieces2[1] == "arg1"
// pieces2[2] == "arg2 could be single-quoted also"
```

This obviously isn't too difficult to accomplish by splitting the string along whitespace and then iterating over the tokens to merge those in a range that are surrounded by quotes, but I don't reinvent wheels unless I have to. Is there a clean way to do this (in C++03)? I'm open to using the Boost libraries; I suspect that there could be a simple implementation using Boost.Spirit, but I'm not familiar enough with it to know for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [Boost.Program_options](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/program_options.html)

Comment: Never thought to look there, but it looks like the `boost::program_options::split_unix()` function might be the ticket. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can do it by regular expression, since c++03 doesn't support regex(c++ 11 does), we can use boost::regex to finish the job.

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

#include "boost/regex.hpp"

int main()
{
    //std::string str = "/path/to/binary arg1 arg2 \"arg3 has multiple words\"";
    std::string str = "/path/to/binary arg1 'arg2 could be single-quoted also'";

    //std::regex rx("([^(\"|')]\\S*|(\"|').+?(\"|'))\\s*");
    boost::regex rx("([^(\"|')]\\S*|(\"|').+?(\"|'))\\s*");
    boost::smatch res;
    while (boost::regex_search (str,res,rx))
    {
        std::cout <<res[0] << std::endl;
        str = res.suffix().str();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Looks like a pretty good solution. One thing I noticed is that the single quotes around the last argument aren't eaten (i.e. they are present in the tokens returned by `regex_search()`. Is there a way to modify the expression so that the quotes aren't present?

Comment: Ah, that's simple. In the while loop, use regex_replace to remove the quotes. `boost::regex re("^(\"|')|(\"|')$"); // put it outside the loop
  std::string result_str = res[0];
  std::cout << boost::regex_replace(result_str,re,"")<<std::endl;
  str = res.suffix().str();` or just call `std::remove_if`